# Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: _MainBody is not defined - Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I am super, super new to this subject (Today it is my first day): end 2 end unit tests and I discovered puppeteer.

I have my page where I launch a function to fetch some info from an API and than I display the info on the page.

What I want to do is the following.
I want to make this end 2 end test to check if the page has a header and a footer + if the function gets called and gives a response if called.

Bellow I will attach my code.
The question is: Why does it says that _MainBody is not defined since that is the name of the function and the file name where everything happens: fetch the data and display it.

I will attach it below so you can understand what I did and where is the problem.

Thank you in advance to everyone that is willing to help.

e2e.test.tsx

```
import getRandomBeer from "./MainBody";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";


describe("myTest", () => {
  let browser: puppeteer.Browser;
  let page: puppeteer.Page;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      page = await browser.newPage();
      
  });
    
  it('The function gets called', async () => {
    await page.goto('LINK');
  
      console.log(await page.evaluate(() => typeof getRandomBeer === 'function'));
  
    })

    afterAll(() => browser.close());
});
```

file where everything happens and where the function gets called to fetch the data

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import Beer from './BeerClass';


//Function that gets called in order to fetch the beers one by one
async function getRandomBeer() {
    const req = await fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/random');
    const data = await req.json();
    console.log(data[0]);
    return data[0] as Beer;
}



const nBeers = 30;

function MainBody() {


    const [beerData, setBeerData] = useState<Beer[]>([]);

    console.log(beerData);

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //NOTE: Some of the beers come with NULL for the image link so some of the beers don't have a photo unfortunatelly.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    //Saving all the beers inside an array that initally gets filled with zeros and than I map the beers inside it and than I se the beerData so I can display it below
    //It waits until it does not fetch all the beers
    useEffect(() => {
        Promise.all(new Array(nBeers).fill(0).map(getRandomBeer).reverse()).then(setBeerData);
    }, [])

    //Display the beer data, beer after beer
    return (
        <div id="beers">
            {beerData && beerData.map((beerData) => {
                return (
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="image"> <img src={beerData.image_url} width={30} height={100}></img>
                            <div className='text'>
                                <h4>{beerData.name} </h4>
                                <p>{beerData.tagline}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
            )}
        </div>
    );
};


export default { MainBody , getRandomBeer};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this after defining page
now you can use your function in the callback you use in evaluate.
evaluate returns the element you define

```
await page.exposeFunction("getRandomBeer", getRandomBeer);
```